# How to keep dynamically sized text from hiding behind padding of Kivy TextInput

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on making a text input box resize the text so all characters are still visible as the length of the input grows. I've been able to resize the text using the code below. However, if I type to fast the first character gets pushed behind the padding of the `TextInput`. How could the text be reset to accommodate the reset of the font size?

```
class TeamNameField(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TeamNameField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(text=self.checkTextSize)

    def checkTextSize(self, TeamNameField, text):
        print(self.right)
        print(self.text[-1:])
        if self.cursor_pos[0] > (self.right - 50):
            self.font_size -= 10
```

[image]

I don't prefer using the cursor position to determine the length of the string but it's the best I've come up with so far.

Comment: There was a PR that fixes not showing the whole character as it's visible in your screenshot. Try updating to the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Text input uses an internal label to display its text, and labels have sizes. Each time the text changes, update the input width based on the label texture width. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import sp

gui = '''
MyTextInput
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    size_hint: None, None
    height: sp(50)
    font_size: sp(30)
    multiline: False
'''


class MyTextInput(TextInput):

    def on_text(self, obj, text):
        self.width = self._lines_labels[0].width + sp(30)


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(gui)

Test().run()
```